# how to unserialize this data with php?

Tags: php, python, serialization

I've got this data set which was probably serialised with php function serialize()

```
C:8:"Poreikis":768:{a:14:{s:3:"_id";a:1:{s:2:"id";s:4:"5889";}s:5:"_data";a:12:{s:2:"id";s:4:"5889";s:11:"stokojantis";s:4:"2748";s:17:"parent_kategorija";s:1:"1";s:10:"kategorija";s:1:"3";s:11:"pavadinimas";s:6:"Komoda";s:9:"aprasymas";s:89:"blah blah";s:7:"pasiula";N;s:6:"active";s:1:"Y";s:10:"created_at";s:19:"2013-02-10 12:10:48";s:10:"updated_at";s:19:"2013-02-10 12:10:48";s:7:"creator";s:4:"1842";s:6:"editor";N;}s:7:"_values";a:0:{}s:6:"_state";i:3;s:13:"_lastModified";a:0:{}s:9:"_modified";a:0:{}s:10:"_oldValues";a:0:{}s:15:"_pendingDeletes";a:0:{}s:15:"_pendingUnlinks";a:0:{}s:20:"_serializeReferences";b:0;s:17:"_invokedSaveHooks";b:0;s:4:"_oid";i:2;s:8:"_locator";N;s:10:"_resources";a:0:{}}}
```

I've tried `unserialize()` function:

```
var_dump( unserialize($var) );
```

and I've got this:

```
PHP Warning:  Class __PHP_Incomplete_Class has no unserializer in /root/hacked.php on line 4
object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#1 (1) {
  ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=>
  string(8) "Poreikis"
}
```

and I've also tried this with python:

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/env python
  2 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
  3 
  4 import pprint
  5 import phpserialize
  6 from path import path
  7
  8 #filename   = sys.argv[1]
  9 content     = u'_THAT_STRING_FROM_TOP'
 10
 11 unser = phpserialize.unserialize(content)
 13 print unser
```

got this

```
~# python unserialize.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hacked.py", line 11, in <module>
    unser = phpserialize.unserialize(content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/phpserialize.py", line 522, in loads
    object_hook, array_hook)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/phpserialize.py", line 512, in load
    return _unserialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/phpserialize.py", line 510, in _unserialize
    raise ValueError('unexpected opcode')
```

Seems that variable maybe invalid? Ok, so now about this data.

There's ORM engine in PHP called "Doctrine", and there's a model class in doctrine called 'BaseRecycleBin.php', which is actually defining a table called '_deleted_items', which stores this kind of value. And I've even found that [serialization class](http://svn.doctrine-project.org/branches/0.11/lib/Doctrine/Parser/Serialize.php) in doctrine. Which seems to be doesn't do anything irregular at all.

So main question is: how to unserialize this string?

Also if it's possible to answer, does Doctrine can restore that data back from that table? Cause this is my original intension, to construct queries from lots of serialised strings, which originally are from that '_deleted_items' table.

Comment: Was that data stored in the $_SESSION? When you serialize an object and store it in the session, you must make sure the class is defined before you session_start.

Comment: And, more generally, you can only unserialize PHP class instances like this in a context where the class is defined. That's why it's giving you messages about "incomplete class Poreikis".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php) on object serialization (emphasis mine):

> In order to be able to [unserialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) an object, **the class of that object needs to be defined**. That is, if you have an object of class A and serialize this, you'll get a string that refers to class A and contains all values of variables contained in it. If you want to be able to unserialize this in another file, an object of class A, **the definition of class A must be present in that file first**.

Your serialized string contains an object of type `Poreikis`, so when you want to unserialize it, you first need to have that type definition available.

An example of how you could just use an associative array for this:

```
$data = array(
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'key3' => 42
);
// then either serialize that
$serialized = serialize($data);
// or make it a JSON which is supported by many languages
$jsonencoded = json_encode($data);
```

On a second thought though, your `Poreikis` seems to have a `_data` field which already is an associative array and seems to contain all the important information you probably want. So you can just access that field and encode that instead of manually transferring your data to a new array.

Comment: so you mean i can't write just a standalone script to unserialize this?

Comment: You can, but that script needs to contain the type definition as well. This is because an object contains behavior not just simple data, so when you restore the object you need to make sure that the behavior is then there as well. As an alternative you could use a plain associative array instead where you just store your data. Then you could also just create a JSON output which is a lot more accepted than PHP’s serialization.

Comment: if you could provide example i'm would gladly accept your answer. I found these data in database table, so I have no way to get any object from php..?

Comment: i mean unserialize to array/dictionary.. or smtng. i don't need object

Comment: i still can't understand how to parse provided string in topic. i need to extract that god damned column names with values. cause i want to use them for constructing queries, to restore that data =/ i mean you can even write this in python or java or c, i need to parse that string and take everything out from there for 1500 serialised strings.. now you showed me how to serialize array.. which is why i need this..?

Comment: If you have an array encoded with `json_encode`, then you can use `json.loads` in Python to get the data back as a dictionary. And no, you cannot parse the string from your question (in PHP) if you do not have the type defined. In Python you can use the dynamic typing to make it work: `phpserialize.unserialize(content, object_hook=phpserialize.phpobject)`